# Need help with designing a form to capture email from a simple HTML form to a local excel spreadsheet / database

Tags: html, database, transfer

I have created a simple web page in Photoshop and want to use it to capture emails. I am only using the page on a local computer and need the email captured to download / transfer to a local excel spreadsheet on the same computers hard drive.
Looking for suggestions or HTML code to use on the page...
I would appreciate any help you guys can give me!!
IM LOST!! I have played and tried everything that I can think of...
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There's no fast-and-easy way to do something like that, especially if you're trying to save it to an Excel spreadsheet.

You'll have to look into using a scripting language such as PHP or ASP.Net. Do you have any experience writing code?

Comment: Not really..  I have looked into it but get lost to be honest with you..  suggestions?

Comment: how about from a form to a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my suggestion is use google docs , learn it by this [link](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809)

Then you can download the spreadsheet from google docs.

Not a programmer kind of way to solve things , but at lease it solve things ....

Comment: darn lol that's what i was about to propose. http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/02/add-data-to-google-spreadsheets-using.html

Comment: this is SO , you have to be fast! lol ... 8 view in 10 minutes  , lol

Comment: Great start, only problem is I need to enter info just the capture formm-) PRESS ENTER  and have the info transferred.

Comment: cliff , click the correct button and give me an up vote if you think this answer your question. I want reputation .... badly ... "enter info"? "press enter"? I don't understand your question ....